# running a os.system / subprocess.call returns Syntax error

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I have this bash command I want to run from Python2.7:

```
time ( s=172.20.16 ; for i in $(seq 1 254) ; do ( ping -n -c 1 -w 1 $s.$i 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && printf "%-16s %s\n" $s.$i responded ) & done ; wait ; echo )
```

I tried running it like this:

```
cmd = 'time ( s=172.20.16 ; for i in $(seq 1 254) ; do ( ping -n -c 1 -w 1 $s.$i 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && printf "%-16s %s\n" $s.$i responded ) & done ; wait ; echo )'

#1. subprocess.call(cmd.split())
#2. subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
#3. os.system(cmd)
```

But all returned */bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")*, while running it from `bash` worked prefectly. I also tried adding a `/bin/bash` to the head of the command, but that didn't work.

When using `os.system('bash "{}"'.format(cmd))` it didn't crash with the previous error, but the loop unfolded incorecctly (it printed 1..254 instead of using them as the IP suffix)

I managed to make it work by saving the command in a bash script and then calling the script from python, but I would rather do that directly. What is the problem here?

Comment: Your assignment to `cmd` isn't even valid Python.

Comment: `time` is a *bash* builtin. It's not guaranteed to be/do what you expect in other shells, particularly including `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I also tried using /usr/bin/time after verifying this is the `time` I'm using with `which time`

Comment: @CIsForCookies, `/usr/bin/time` has different syntax. You can't pass it a compound command the way you can with the builtin. (You *could* use `['time', 'sh', '-c', cmd]`, on the other hand; that way you're passing it a single simple command, `sh`).

Comment: Also, `which time` is completely useless/meaningless in this context; `which` doesn't know that shell functions, builtins, or aliases even *exist*. If you want to know which implementation of `time` you're using in bash, you want `type time`, not `which time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shell=True` uses `/bin/sh`. `/bin/sh` is not `bash`.

Leaving all the problems with the shell script in place, but invoking it with bash, would look like the following:

```
cmd = 'time ( s=172.20.16 ; for i in $(seq 1 254) ; do ( ping -n -c 1 -w 1 $s.$i 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && printf "%-16s %s\n" $s.$i responded ) & done ; wait ; echo )'
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', cmd])
```

---

Rewriting it to actually be a better shell script might instead look like:

```
cmd = r'''
time {
  s=172.20.16
  for ((i=1; i<=254; i++)); do
    { ping -n -c 1 -w 1 "$s.$i" >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
      printf "%-16s %s\n" "$s.$i" "responded"
    } &
  done
  wait
  echo
}
'''
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', cmd])
```

Note that we're using `{ ...; }`, not `( ... )`, for grouping (thus avoiding more subshell creations than necessary); and that we're *always* quoting substitutions.

Comment: I'm using your answer, but now I'm stuck with another thing... the output assigned to `x = subprocess.check_output(...)` is `'\n'` even though I get more lines of output, that somehow slip away from `x`

Comment: Are those lines really *output*, or are they on stderr?

Comment: ...if you want to combine those two streams, add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` as a separate keyword argument to `subprocess.call()`.

Comment: yeah... I just did it to check your previous comment. Of course the output I saw was actually stderr. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you are splitting by space to construct the array of commands/parameters for the suprocess call method; but notice that there are parameters that include spaces, so it should count as a single parameter, not two (ie this one: `"%-16s %s\n"`)

Comment: not explains all of the cases, so I don't think this is the main issue

Comment: right, Charles Duffy's answer addresses the second case.

Answer (score -1):

Try using subprocess as per this link [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("{}".format(cmd).split())
```

Comment: `split()` is a problem no matter whether you use `subprocess` or not.

Comment: Good to know. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Without `shell=True`, the expected format of the `args` parameter to `subprocess.call` is a list with one entry per argv value. Using `string.split()` to generate that list works for very simple cases like `ls hello.txt`, but it'll change `ls "Hello World.txt"` to `['ls', '"Hello', 'World.txt"']`. And for compound commands that require a shell to connect them, you have bugs even when using shell-syntax-aware replacements like `shlex.split()`, and really need to rewrite to either let a shell do the splitting, or to connect the processes in native Python.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.